# Xcode and ios - are storybords a good idea for dynamicly generated menus and content?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

Suppose you have a front menu generated dynamicly meaning all the different items loaded runtime can take you to entirely different scenes. And in the case where the scene is shared, different parts may have been done visible/hidden and lead to (again) entirely different scenes.

In other app languages (Android/java) or Delphi/ios this has been very easy to handle myself. now, geting acquainted with xcode/swift I am wondering if storyboards will be more of a hassle than advantage? (Compared to loading xib files myself and starting transitions/segues)

However, since I don't see many people on the net posting example on how to handle and code these things themselves (I have found partial snippets here and there), I am thinking I may on the wrong path, and I am overlooking something?

Comment: You'd likely get better answers if you'd rewrite the first paragraph to explain in concrete terms what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: The content and menus are downloaded online, so presentation is very dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

I stopped using storyboards a while ago. Especially the segue structure is something that is annoying to me.

Instead of checking which segue is being prepared and populating the correct destination controller with values it's just so much simpler to create a VC and populate it then just let the navigation controller push it.

I think my projects are much cleaner after I removed the storyboards and the code is much simpler to follow and debug.

Story boards are great for prototyping though. And you can always break out individual xibs from the storyboard if you want to start with a storyboard to get something up and running quickly. Another option is to build your view in story board but instantiate them and push them on the stack in code instad of the storyboard segues

comparing this:

```
let detailsController = DetailsViewController()
detailsController.object = object
navigationController?.pushViewController(detailsController, animated: true)
```

to this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "some identifier" {
        if let detailController = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailsController {
                detailController.object = object
        }
    }
}
```

Where the second one is a callback that you can't simply step into from the location of your initiation of the segue

Another befit of keeping the individual VCs in xibs is that you keep one file per responsibility and you have an easier time navigating to the controller you are seeking and to merge if working with someone else.

Tl; dr;

In my opinion storyboards are to messy.
When working with xibs there are benefits:

1. Cleaner segues that can be easily debugged
2. One file per responsibility. Can quick search views by searching for files
3. Much easier merge when sharing code

Comment: It's a great idea to use ARM assembler and Vim instead of Objective-C and XCode since you don't use storyboards. Believe me.

Answer (score 1):

Question seems a liiiitle bit vague.
My understanding stopped at "front menu generated dynamicly".

I met a case where the actual UI of the iOS app could not be determined / foreseen at coding time: the app would connect to a server and depending on context, the server would send an XML / JSON describing the UI: a button here, a text filed there, an image there, and so on. All UI was then conjured programatically.
In this case, yeah, you cannot phisically use storyboards. Nor XIBs for that matter.

Another case: I met an application that had no "UI sequentiality". You could not use a navigation controller, or XIBs in a certain order, etc...they wanted it all done "the web style": lots of buttons, the user might click anything, you were faced with even more buttons, there was no way to foresee where one could end up at the next step.
I did use a storyboard, but it was my worst decision: in the end I ended up creating segues between most of the views. What I initially imagined to be a tree, ended up as a complete graph. It just happened to evolve that way, in the absence of clear specifications. I knew it's horrible, but I wasn't allowed the chance to start over with a more suited design. 
So no! No storyboards in this case, either.

If your task looks like normal Apple / iPhone flow, then I hold nothing against storyboards.

Answer (score 1):

> However, since I don't see many people on the net posting example on how to handle and code these things themselves...I am thinking I may on the wrong path, and I am overlooking something?

**Storyboards work fine for dynamic content.** Storyboards simply let you set up different "scenes" for your app, and also the transitions or *segues* between those scenes. Demos often show segues being triggered by some action, like a tap on a button or table cell because that's easy to set up without any code. But you can just as easily trigger a segue programmatically.

Let's say you've got a table that lists people, departments, and buildings in your company's directory, and when the user taps a row you want to transition to one of several new scenes depending on the type of data in that row. Tapping on a person would show contact info, for example, while tapping on a building would show the building location on a map. So you set up your storyboard like this (I've left out the department scene -- it's just more of the same idea):

[image: storyboard]

[image: scenes]

Now, when the user taps a row in the directory, your code can look at which row was tapped, get the data associated with that row, figure out what kind of scene to transition to, and invoke the required segue using its identifier, like:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("PersonSegue", sender:self)
```

So, now you've successfully segued to a new scene without knowing ahead of time which scene tapping the row would lead to. Tap some other row and the data associated with that row would lead you to decide to switch to a different scene.

Storyboards are actually a big help here for at least two reasons:

1. It's a heck of a lot easier to configure a segue in a storyboard than to write code that creates each of the segues you need, or to repeatedly write the code that makes the transition directly. You could factor the code for all of those transitions into a separate class, but then you'd have something very much like `UIStoryboardSegue`.
2. Having the segues defined in a storyboard lets you see all the possible transitions from one scene to another. That's very useful for conveying how the app works to other people on your team, stakeholders, etc.